# Office script does not process all data

Tags: office-scripts, excel-online

I have created an office script (cannot use VBA, because it has to work in Excel online), which transforms data and converts it to table. However, it only works only if I have no more that 4 rows of data, if there are more rows the rest does not get processed fully, seems like the script runs out of time and runs last lines of code or something.

Source data table (in sheet2) looks like this:

| Code | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 | Column9 | Column10 | Column11 | PowerAppsId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| Dia = 88.90Thk = 6.30Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 315155Pcs = 19Mtr = 228.00Cor = Sor = Btc = 21KE020558 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1d4dfa2c-ed94-4152-adcd-6700e208608f |
| Dia = 88.90Thk = 6.30Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 36829EPcs = 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470271 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | c7a27d77-36bd-407e-8131-7180d753b79f |
| Dia = 219,1Thk = 12,5Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 032111Pcs = 4Mtr = 48Sor = STOCKCor = Btc = 21C1010406 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ded5157e-f82f-46b1-897a-1f2874f40900 |
| Dia = 88.90Thk = 6.30Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 36829EPcs = 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470273 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5fd82d95-a416-4d1f-ab0f-bee896a5d5e2 |
| Dia = 219,1Thk = 12,5Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 032111Pcs = 4Mtr = 48Sor = STOCKCor = Btc = 21C1010406 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 743fd8c3-8e79-4d72-86af-f46f50a44644 |
| Dia = 88.90Thk = 6.30Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 36829EPcs = 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470271 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8bb45032-cab4-452d-a044-c189461967a7 |
| Dia = 88.90Thk = 6.30Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 315155Pcs = 19Mtr = 228.00Cor = Sor = Btc = 21KE020558 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | e7e3cddd-0ae2-40a1-bbc0-1191817f8f02 |
| Dia = 88.90Thk = 6.30Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 36829EPcs = 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470271 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 25347ead-8ccf-43e4-a8f0-b34517dc8526 |
| Dia = 219,1Thk = 12,5Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 032111Pcs = 4Mtr = 48Sor = STOCKCor = Btc = 21C1010406 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 852ff0b5-41ef-42ba-afa0-18cb7b83bf80 |
| Dia = 88.90Thk = 6.30Len = 12000Qua = S460MHHea = 36829EPcs = 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470273 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | a45eada1-b926-48bf-872b-2f5a8150a5b1 |

Then I run the script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
    // Replace all "Dia = " with "" on extended range obtained by extending down from range A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).replaceAll("Dia = ", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Thk =" with "" on extended range obtained by extending down from range A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).replaceAll("Thk =", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Len =" with "" on extended range obtained by extending down from range A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).replaceAll("Len =", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Qua =" with "" on extended range obtained by extending down from range A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).replaceAll("Qua =", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Hea =" with "" on extended range obtained by extending down from range A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).replaceAll("Hea =", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Pcs =" with "" on extended range obtained by extending down from range A3 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).replaceAll("Pcs =", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Sor = " with " SOR" on range A3:A6 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3:A6").replaceAll("Sor = ", " SOR", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Cor = " with "" on range A3:A6 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3:A6").replaceAll("Cor = ", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Btc =" with "" on range A3:A6 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3:A6").replaceAll("Btc =", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Replace all "Mtr =" with "" on range A3:A6 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("A3:A6").replaceAll("Mtr =", "", {completeMatch: false, matchCase: false});
    // Text to columns on range A3:A6 on selectedSheet
    for (let row = 0; row < selectedSheet.getRange("A3:A6").getRowCount() ; row++) {
        let sourceRange = selectedSheet.getRange("A3:A6");
        let destinationRange = selectedSheet.getRange("A3");
        let sourceRangeValues = sourceRange.getRow(row).getValues()[0][0].toString().split(/[ ]/)
        destinationRange.getOffsetRange(row, 0).getResizedRange(0, sourceRangeValues.length - 1).setValues([sourceRangeValues]);
    }
    let sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    // Delete extended range obtained by extending down from range 2:2 on selectedSheet
    sheet1.getRange("2:2").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
    let table1 = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    // Paste to table table1 cell in row 0 on column Dia from extended range obtained by extending down, then right from range A3 on selectedSheet
    table1.getColumn("Dia").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getRow(0).copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.right), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    selectedSheet.getRange("3:3").getExtendedRange(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.down).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
}
```

but it outputs table like this (to sheet1):

| Dia | Thk | Len | Qua | Hea | Pcs | Mtr | Cor | Btc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88.90 | 6.30 | 12000 | S460MH | 315155 | 19 | 228.00 | SOR | 21KE020558 |
| 88.90 | 6.30 | 12000 | S460MH | 36829E | 19 | 228 | SOR | Z000470271 |
| 219,1 | 12,5 | 12000 | S460MH | 032111 | 4 | 48 | SORSTOCK | 21C1010406 |
| 88.90 | 6.30 | 12000 | S460MH | 36829E | 19 | 228 | SOR | Z000470273 |
| 219,1 12,5 12000 S460MH 032111 4Mtr = 48Sor = STOCKCor = Btc = 21C1010406 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 88.90 6.30 12000 S460MH 36829E 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470271 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 88.90 6.30 12000 S460MH 315155 19Mtr = 228.00Cor = Sor = Btc = 21KE0205583 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 88.90 6.30 12000 S460MH 36829E 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470271 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 219,1 12,5 12000 S460MH 032111 4Mtr = 48Sor = STOCKCor = Btc = 21C1010406 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 88.90 6.30 12000 S460MH 36829E 19Mtr = 228Cor = Sor = Btc = Z000470273 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

As you can see, first four rows are processed correctly, but the rest only partially. What can be causing this? Script shows no errors

I have tried running the same script locally - saved excel online file as a local copy, but results are the same. Script works normally only if I have up to four rows of data

Comment: I haven't analysed it detail but your code has A3 to A6 in a few spots, that's exactly four rows, could that be your problem?

Comment: Somehow, i completely missed that. Will try to edit that soon and see if that fixes script

Answer (score 0):

Range was not defined correctly in part of the script

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy.